# Ubuntu can not connect to freenas share

Tags: mount, samba, cinnamon, nas

I have a FreeNas server that has been running fine for some time. I am able to log into my **FreeNas**'s CIFS share from a windows computer, and I am able to log on to CIFS shares from other Windows Computers on my Ubuntu computer. However, accessing the share has proved troublesome.

I am using the Cinnamon gui for my computer and seem to have 3 **Files** applications installed. Two of them give me the error

```
 Could not display "smb://fancyoaks.local/fancyoaks/".
 The location is not a folder
```

However, i can use the 3rd Files program here and at least open the share. once it is open though, i am unable to do anything to the files already within the share

Ex. Copying a file out to computer

```
 Error while copying.
 There was an error getting information about "ExampleDIR".
 Show more details
 The name :1.148 was not provided by any .service files
```

How can i make this browse-able to my Ubuntu box?